# Spring Config Server @Value returns null

Tags: spring, server, config

I have a config server returning values correctly, and I can pull values without any issue except for this one script which I presume is due to using @PostConstruct. However, I have tried multiple solutions without success. Does anyone have any suggestions for changes to make this work?

Output from Config Server
`

```
{
    "name": "auth-service",
    "profiles": [
        "jdbc"
    ],
    "label": "1.0",
    "version": null,
    "state": null,
    "propertySources": [
        {
            "name": "auth-service-jdbc",
            "source": {
                "spring.datasource.url": "jdbc:mysql://x.x.x.x:3306/test?useUnicode=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false",
                "spring.datasource.username": "xxxx",
                "spring.datasource.password": "xxxxx",
                "jwt.secret": "xxxxxxx",
                "jwt.expiration": "86400"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

`

The script with which I am having issues, secret and expirationTime are always null unless contained within Bootstrap.yml, which is not practical.
`

```
@Component
public class JwtUtil {

    @Value("${jwt.secret}")
    String secret;

    @Value("${jwt.expiration}")
    String expirationTime;

    private Key key;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.key = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(secret.getBytes());
    }
```

`

So far, I have tried using Environment instead of @Value, constructors and with and without @PostConstruct. The only way I have managed to get it to grab the values is when they are in Application.yml or Bootstrap.yml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by not using @PostConstruct after rewriting the JWT implementation